# flash as3 serial port

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, serial-port

Hey trying to bring data in through the serial port but i get this error.
1037: Packages cannot be nested.
I then need to take these values and use 1 to control video playback and the other to control the audio volume

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.XMLSocket;
import flash.events.DataEvent;

public class receiveData extends Sprite
{
    public static const PORT:Number = 5331;
    public static const COMMA:String = ",";
    public static const LOCALHOST:String = "127.0.0.1";

    private var socket:XMLSocket = null;

    public function receiveData()
    {
        super();
        init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        socket = new XMLSocket();
        socket.addEventListener( DataEvent.DATA, doSocketData );
        socket.connect( LOCALHOST, PORT );
    }

    protected function doSocketData( event:DataEvent ):void
    {
        var parts:Array = null;
        var sensorone:Number = 0;
        var sensortwo:Number = 0;
        var values:String = event.data.toString();
        parts = values.split( COMMA );
        trace( parts[0]);
        trace( parts[1]);
        sensorone = new Number( parts[0] );
        sensortwo = new Number( parts[1] );
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does making a socket connection with local host/port 5331 get you to the computer's serial port? Is there something listening on that port that relays data to/from the serial port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need to put that code in a separate AS3 file and set that as the document class or as the class file for a MovieClip you make in Flash.  Alternatively you could use a different IDE like FlashBuilder or FlashDevelop or FDT and avoid the Flash IDE (which as a programmer primarily I feel muddles things up quite a bit).

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=136364 (haha SO won't let me LMGTFY)

Looks like you're on the right track though if you're using tinkerproxy or something of the sort to forward the data (have fun I gotta get myself back into that, check out links in th description of my vid http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71eFWknHKEM&list=UUSz-eugjE1d6yki6ZT51CKg&index=17&feature=plcp :)

Comment: hey i know i never get back to people straight away i'm in college ad have a load of other projects too... i'm actually using arduino for this as well... just after getting back to it now i have my arduino sending the values i want to the serial port but i'm after opening up my flash file again i haven't changed it from what is here but i'm no longer getting an error but it's not doing anything

Comment: @PaddyHallihan, no problem I was doing that project while going to school too I know how it goes.  Sounds like you just need to get some debugging going, you can use trace("got here"); to figure out where in your program it's breaking down.